# The method change(Bar, Bar) is undefined for the type ArrayList<Bar>

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to change the value of a 'Bar' object, I've created a change method that takes 2 bar variables, however when I try and use it on 'list.get(i)' within the compareBar method I get an error that says this method is undefined for the type ArrayList, is this not a Bar object and how do I change it inorder to be so?

```
 public class Envelope {
    ArrayList<Bar> list = new ArrayList<Bar>();


    //Compares and adjusts range of bars accordingly    
    public void compareBars() {
        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if(list.get(i+1).left <= list.get(i).right) {
                if(list.get(i).height >= list.get(i+1).height) {
                    list.change(list.get(i+1),list.get(i));
                }else if(list.get(i+1).height >= list.get(i).height) {
                    list.change(list.get(i),list.get(i+1));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // Modifies ranges of bar values
    public void change(Bar target, Bar replacement) {
        if(target.left < replacement.left) {
            target.right = replacement.left;            
        }
        if (target.left > replacement.left) {
            target.left = replacement.right;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `change` is defined on your `Envelope` type, not `ArrayList<Bar>`. So `list.change` won't work. You'd need `this.change`. Voting to close as typo/non-repro/not-useful-to-others-in-future.

Comment: `change(Bar target, Bar replacement)` is for the class `Envelope` and not a method of class `ArrayList`

Comment: Try using `this.change` instead of `list.change`